# Thread counter Synchronization issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locks

**I am trying to learn Multithreading techniques.**
I tried to implement the synchronized behaviour to increment the counter.
I am using two variables one is **AtomicInteger** and another one with normal counter as **a**.

Issue I am facing is when I am printing the values in thread t3. I am getting different values each time although output expected should be 1000.
When I comment out the **atomicIntegers.increment()** method in **t1** and **t2**  of AtomicInteger counter then I get the value of counter a as 1000. Even though I am using locks.

#### *Can someone Help me in understanding this and how to increment both the counters in a synchronized way together.*

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicIntegers atomicIntegers = new AtomicIntegers();
    Thread t1= new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i =0; i<500; i++) {
//                atomicIntegers.increment();
                atomicIntegers.incrementA();
            }
        }
    };

        Thread t2= new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i =0; i<500; i++) {
//                    atomicIntegers.increment();
                    atomicIntegers.incrementA();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t3= new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    System.out.println(atomicIntegers.getAtomicInteger());
                    System.out.println(atomicIntegers.getA());
                }
            }
        };

//        t3.setPriority(2);
//        t1.setPriority(1);
//        t2.setPriority(3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }
}
```

```java
class AtomicIntegers extends Thread{
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int a =0;
    public ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void increment() {
        atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public  void incrementA() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            a++;
        }
    }

    public int getAtomicInteger() {
        return atomicInteger.get();
    }

    public  int getA() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot expect that `t3` will actually be executed after the other two have finished, neither does `synchronized` impose any sequence - maybe that the threads are executed fast enough without `atomicIntegers.increment()`, so each thread finishes before the others  even can get started

Comment: yeah But the same code gives 1000 or constant result when run on different IDE. Is there any specific reason for that? BTW I am using Intellij

Comment: Your code is basically correct (could use some improvements though). So what exactly is your problem? Your Question is confusing. Is your goal actually trying to increment the atomic integer and the primitive integer together  in [lockstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockstep)? It is difficult trying to nail down your exact concern.

Comment: My concern is why incrementing primitive data type on intellij beahaves differently than that in other compilers.

Comment: @NitinGangwar That last Comment makes your  Question even *more* confusing. You never mentions any other compilers! Do you mean various Java compilers, or other languages than Java? You really need to rewrite the Question.